# I need to make this wordpress press plugin look like the example below using CSS - I've been playing with it for a while and I can't get it right

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to make this plugin for WordPress "post and grids"(https://www.wponlinesupport.com/plugins/) look like the screenshot below.  I want to get the WordPress plugin to display in a grid with borders like the example.

My current plugin with my CSS code https://katekeileydesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Capture.png

The example I'm trying to recreate https://katekeileydesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Capture.-2PNG.png
!

This is the custom CSS I've added already:

```
.pgafu-post-grid-content {
 border-left: 1px solid rgba(130,127,127,0.41);
 padding-right:-50px !important;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(130,127,127,0.41);
 padding: 2px;
 padding-right:2px;
 }

 #pgafu-post-filtr-1 {
  border:1px solid rgba(130,127,127,0.41);
  padding-left: 15px; 
  margin: 20px;
  }

.pgafu-post-title {
 text-decoration:underline;
 text-decoration-color: blue !important; 
 }
```

Comment: Looks like you're almost there just need to change position of text content and size of filters. Can you add example code as well. Can't decide with just CSS.

Comment: Thanks Veey. The base code is like this demo http://demo.wponlinesupport.com/prodemo/post-grid-and-filter-with-popup-pro-demo/grid-filter-view/

Comment: Could you reproduce your code in a snippet? The context might help us answer your question.